# Scala - error: value max is not a member of my custom class

Tags: java, scala

I've got my own class

```
class Foo {
 MyCustomClass value;
 ...
}
```

which consists of MyCustomClass which is java enum with the following signature:

```
enum MyCustomClass{
   ONE(1),
   TWO(2),
   THREE(3)

   private int nominal;

   MyCustomClass(int nominal) {
       this.nominal = nominal;
   }

   public int nominal() {
       return nominal;
   }
}
```

for which i define ordering as:

```
implicit val myCustomClassOrdering = new Ordering[Foo] {
    override def compare(c1: Foo, c2:Foo): Int = {
        c1.value.nominal.compareTo(c2.value.nominal)
    }
}
import myCustomClassOrdering ._
```

and then i'm able to use function max for sequence of objects ofMyCustomClass type. But i got an error trying to use max fucntion in reduceOption function

```
val l = List[Foo](...)
l.reduceOption(_ max _)
```

got error message: `value max is not a member of ...`

What should i do to be able to use it in `reduceOption` with `max` function?

Answer (score 0):

max method delegated for MyCustomClass. Either add ordering for Foo or add another method which returns Foo object according to result of max method call on MyCustomClass values.

```
def op(x: Foo,y: Foo):Foo = {
    if( (x.value max y.value) == x.value) x
    else y
  }

  val b = l.reduceOption( op(_,_) )
```

Comment: fixed his typos, please delete

Comment: oh, yes sorry, i tried to simplify but the exact case is more complex, i've made some changes in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
object FooExtension {
    implicit class RichFoo(c:Foo) {
        def max(c2:Foo) = {
            if(c.value.nominal > c2.value.nominal) c else c2
        }
    }
}

import FooExtension._
```

Now it works but i'm wondering if there is more clear solution where i can rely on built in max and ordering features.